# Inner query where match field is pointer to another class

Tags: android, parse-platform

I develop an application where the database is in Parse. In parse I have the class A which contains several fields. Also I have the class B which two of the fields are the user and another one which is pointer to class A. I want to get all the rows of the class A where the user is equal with the current user. I have tried

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> innerQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("ClassB");
innerQuery.include("user");
innerQuery.include("pointerToClassA");
innerQuery.whereEqualTo("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("ClassA");
query.whereMatchesQuery("pointerToClassA", innerQuery);
```

But I get `Error: bad type for $inQuery`

Also I have seen `matchesKeyInQuery` but I don't what to set for a parameter.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> innerQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("ClassB");
innerQuery.include("user");
innerQuery.include("pointerToClassA");
innerQuery.whereEqualTo("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("ClassA");
query.whereMatchesKeyInQuery("????", "pointerToClassA", innerQuery );
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have a pointer of `Class B` in `Class A` in order to get a relation query to work. `pointerToClassA` is a column in `Class B`, so you can't query on it using a `ParseQuery` instance of `Class A`

Comment: So there isn't any way to achieve the above query without to make two queries in background?